# Moving jar files in R studio server

Tags: r, jar, rstudio-server

I have this error 'Error: NoClassDefFoundError (Java): javax/activation/DataHandler' when using MailR package in R studio. Worked in the past, but suddenly faced with the above error.

[Unable to send email using mailR package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016207/unable-to-send-email-using-mailr-package)

^^ the above post recommended to

- Find the java-mailR folder: system.file("java", package = "mailR")
- Then, copy the two .jar files into that folder. How do you copy the two .jar local files to the path above^?

where exactly is R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0.2/mailR/java located....? I'm using Rstudio server packages. I tried finding locally but I don't think that's right?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nowadays, I would recommend using the blastula package instead of mailR: https://pkgs.rstudio.com/blastula/